# How to use foreign type characters in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography

I need to use Chinese characters in Photoshop CS for Windows 7.  What do I need to set up to make this possible?

Comment: I have never attempted to use e.g. Chinese characters, but I will say that the use of them without a suitable copyeditor who can read the correct dialect of Chinese is not recommended. Especially in the realm of professional design. And tatoos.

Comment: Fortunately I am working with one who is fluent, but yes you are definitely correct, thanks!

Comment: @Big It should work "out of the box" provided you have fonts with the appropriate characters.  I've never had a problem with chinese characters in photoshop (though I haven't worked with hanzi in original CS, only CS3 & newer)

Comment: The font you are using needs to support the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer for Windows is to install a Chinese Input Method editor (IME). This can be done in the control panel under language settings I think.  I believe the main Chinese IMEs tend to assume you can draw and read Chinese characters or know the standard PinYing latinizations of pronunciations in an official dialect.

You could skip the above if you only need to cut & paste text-strings from elsewhere.

Obviously, your choice of fonts may be a bit restricted (compared to ASCII). You may want to obtain and install some additional fonts to supplement those of the ones provided by Microsoft that actually contain Chinese glyphs.